# Node process.env variables loaded from env.sh

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables

I know that you can use a library dotenv to set process.env variables when writing an express app, but at work I use Python and we regularly use shell scripts (env.sh for example) to set environmental variables, especially locally.

So I wrote and then sourced an env.sh script to get credentials for my mongo database but I noticed something strange.  When I defined the variables in env.sh, I defined them like so:

```
#env.sh
export username=blahbblahblah 
export password=blahblahbalbha
```

Then I ran

```
source env.sh
```

I checked env and saw the variables listed as expected.  But then I entered node and I saw the variables listed in process.env as

```
user=blablabhablabha\n
password=blabhalbhabl\n
```

So my question is, why does node include the newline character when bash linux doesn't?  It must be that newline in the env.sh file, because I was able to fix this issue by writing my script as follows:

```
export username=blabhablha; export password=blabhalbahbal;
```

Comment: In windows i had no such problem

Comment: Probably related to doing this in WSL -- different line endings between Windows and Linux.